# Android - How to show a vertical line on the background of a ListView (and according to row height)?

Tags: android, listview, background, line, drawable

How to show a vertical line on the background, such as the one highlighted in blue on the image below?

[image]

In this example, I have a ListView with ImageView elements (and TextView, but it is not related to the line), and I want a vertical line on the background of these items to feel like they are "connected" to each one.

And also, note that the vertical line does not fill all the background.

The vertical line is on the left, and it is not equal for the all cases. Sometimes it fills all the row height (in most of ListView rows) and sometimes it just fills the half of row height (in the last item of the ListView and outside of the ListView, on the top, where we can see the big ImageView with the star icon).

**Updated**

I tried the suggestion proposed by Hellboy, and it almost work perfectly. I modified the proposed code for my case:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

<View
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3399CC"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" >
</ImageView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

the RelativeLayout with the width="40dp" (the same as the original ImageView I was working with), height="match_parent (the same as he said), gravity="center" (to let them in the center of the row height) and layout_marginLeft="15dp" (to let a space to the left margin). In the ImageView, I added marginTop="10dp" and marginBottom="10dp", and with it, the blue vertical line appears. But I have other elements in the same row, so I have a parent layout (a linear layout). My parent layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutservicerow">
```

So, this parent layout above, has the described RelativeLayout and other LinearLayout with the other row elements. But the code results in **flattened images**. Why does this happen?! It seems like the RelativeLayout consider its height as the ImageView height (40dp) and does consider its marginTop and marginBottom, and with this the image is flattened.

Waiting more answers to this problem. I'll try another alternatives.

Comment: Use relative layout as parent layout,And then add two views in top and bottom of the image with preferred width with background color,It should work... try it out dude....

Comment: I updated the question. I tried your proposed solution, too. Put one view before (on the top of) the ImageView with the background color works, but put other in the bottom does not work, because the second one overlaps the image.

Comment: If I put only one (I choose the first, before the ImageView), it will be with the same height of the parent, which assumes the same height of the ImageView (ie, the line is not shown). So, I put margins on the top and on the bottom of the ImageView, but similar problem of height occurs, and the ImageView is flattened.

Comment: Is it flattened horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Vertically. The width is the same, but the image is flattened vertically.

Comment: For this reason, my guess was the RelativeLayout with the same height of the ImageView not considering the margins of top and bottom (totalheight=40dp), and because the ImageView has height 40dp but has margins with total size of 20dp (marginTop = 10dp, marginBottom = 10dp), it is flattened. It seems like that to me.

Comment: Try to set width and height of RelativeLayout to ImageView width/height + margins

Comment: The RelativeLayout width is already static, with the same width I choose for ImageView. But the RelativeLayout height can not be static.

Comment: The RelativeLayout height can not be static because if the row is expanded (for example, if the TextView has a text which makes the row height be larger than 40dp+10dp+10dp), the parent should assume its height and "his brother" (the RelativeLayout, and consequently, the vertical line) height should assume this same size, and expand the line height, too.

Comment: Hey, Hellboy! I tried one more thing with your tip, modified again, and I've got an advance! It is almost done! Instead of using the margins (top and bottom) in the ImageView, I just encapsulated the ImageView in ANOTHER RelativeLayout (after the View which simulates the vertical line) and used in it, paddings (top and bottom), and it worked!!!

Comment: But I still have the problem with the last row... It has all the row height, and it is supposed to has half of it.

Comment: @SarahSakamoto check out the comment in my answer

Comment: @dineshsharma Before trying the 9-patch I tried to just encapsulate the ImageView and got this. But I did not solve the problem. I'm reading your suggestions, too. I am online.

Comment: @dineshsharma Thanks a lot! I'll try your approach later! You made me believe it was possible, and with many ways to implement it. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can replace your ImageView with something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/navy_blue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and of course in your first and last element you need to manipulate the height of the `View` and align it to Top or Bottom

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it now and almost work perfectly! But I have a parent layout (a linear layout in this case, because I have other elements in the same row). With your answer, I tried to put the parent layout with sons: the Relative Layout like your answer (which has the View simulating the line and the ImageView) and the others sons.

Comment: I will put the modifications I did and explain the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want TextView to take te rest of the screen, what you need to do is to set layou_weight="1" and layout_width="0dp" in your TextView

Comment: In fact, my layout is more complicated than that. I have other elements in the row, instead of just a TextView. I put only the TextView to simplify the question, because my question was about the vertical line on the background of the ImageView. I created another layout to take care of the other elements which are in the side of the ImageView.

Answer (score 4):

I got it.

I've persisted in trying to fix the problem of the **Updated** section of my question (based on the solution initially proposed by @Hellboy) and I got results! So, how I achieved an answer to my own question, I decided to put as an answer.

The first step was to configure the XML file such as the code below.

**Part of the final XML corresponding to the row layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutservicerow">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/verticallineview"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#3399CC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_image"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" >
            </ImageView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutotherrowelements">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Explaining the XML:

Here we have the parent layout (linearlayoutservicerow) and inside it: a RelativeLayout (proposed by @HellBoym, with the structured discussed in the final of my question) and the LinearLayout to other elements of the row (layoutotherrowelements). Summarizing... What I modified?

The initial code resulted in flattened images because the RelativeLayout (parent) did not consider the ImageView marginTop and marginBottom, so the image was flattened vertically. (And if we let without margin, the RelativeLayout would mantain the same size and the vertical line would not appear on the top and on the bottom of image.) We must have a space between the ImageView and the RelativeLayout initially proposed, in order to show the line, but if it does not recognize the margin, how to create this space?

I just "encapsulated" the ImageView in another RelativeLayout (inside that parent RelativeLayout), and changed the margin parameters of the ImageView to padding parameters of this capsule RelativeLayout.

**The problem of the last row**

It results in the layout with a line background, but we still have the problem of the last row. In fact, this row is different, and in this case, it must have its height modified to not have the same parent's height. I decided to put at least, the ImageView's height and it worked! Remember to convert the value in dp to pixel, because the function getLayoutParams has all parameters expressed in pixels.

So, in the Adapter, we put the following code:

```
if(position==(getCount()-1)){
View my_line = (View)
    row.findViewById(R.id.verticallineview);
    //40dp, this is the ImageView height
    int dpsize = 40;
    //convert the height in dp unit to pixel (because the parameter is in px)
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpsize, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
    my_line.getLayoutParams().height = px;
}
```

And that is it!!!

It is worth mentioning that @dinesh sharma proposed other interesting alternative using 9-patch, that I will try later.

I did not want to use image as background (that is why I started asking about drawable), because my final goal was to improve this solution to make all dynamic (including the vertical line color), and I believe with image I could not achieve it. But in my original question I did not mention that, so if I have success with this other approach, I will accept it as correct answer.

Thanks for all your help! In my current solution I used the @Hellboy's clue of using a RelativeLayout and a View, and the @dinesh sharma's clue to verify if it is the last row of the ListView. I hope this answer and the others helps more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use transparent 9-patch image as a background for you list view.

For creating nine-patch image please follow this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Why to use a nine-patch and not a drawable?

Comment: Instead of playing with each row Ill suggest to apply at single place using nine-patch image

Comment: At a single place? But it is a ListView, I don't know previously how many row it will have (it is generated dynamically), and what each row height will be. For this reason, I must consider the each row height and apply in each one.

Comment: yes that is also the way to do it. give padding to relative layout and that image as background.

Comment: I think one possibility could be using the 9-patch as the background of the RelativeLayout which actually has the ImageView. It would be the background and be expanded if the row height be larger actual heigh... But I think this solution would present the same problem regarding the ImageView flattened.

Comment: Because the problem with the solution using the RelativeLayout is that it assumes the child's height and flatten its son (the ImageView).

Comment: Ah, but if I have an image as background (9-patch) I could use padding instead of ImageView's margin. Ok, I will try this approach and I tell you if it worked or not! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, and how could I solve the problem of the last item background, being just half of row height, with the 9-patch solution?

Comment: you should make 3 nine patch images one for top blank second for bottom blank and one for top and bottom fill. and in your adapter check that is position is 0 then apply top blank image if position is last of list then bottom blank and rest with the top and bottom image

Comment: Can I divide 9-patchs in the same background and use different ones?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44944/discussion-between-dinesh-sharma-and-sarah-sakamoto)

Answer (score 1):

Now verified answer

your image in item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/m"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

three bg nine patch images for drawable
[image: top blank]  [image: fill content]  [image: bottom blank]

Handling in Adapter:

```
    if(position==0)
        holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
    if(position==(getCount()-1))
        holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.t);
```

Finaly got output:

[image]    [image]

Comment: red Images i have made in MSPaint so its not transparent they are white you can make the white portion as transparent and then try it