# Creating a very customised listview on android (i.e. a vertical line with speech bubbles lined up)

Tags: android, listview

I've got a normal listview however our design team kindly made something, which does look good, for a presentation and as you can guess there is now demand for it to look like this!

Tracked listview

[image]

But I'm struggling to find something even close to what I need and I don't really know where to start!

Each item at the moment is a row list item in a listview, so how do I get a almost git style track line that reflects the status of the item inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your ListView, do not use any padding or divider.

Here similar questions:

[Android - How to show a vertical line on the background of a ListView (and according to row height)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037913/android-how-to-show-a-vertical-line-on-the-background-of-a-listview-and-accor)

[How do create this type of Listview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747508/how-do-create-this-type-of-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after failing at using google Ozgur kindly pointed me in the right direction so what I ended up with was an an order list activity (order_list_activity.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F1EFF3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/OrderList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector_item">
    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

(There was a list selector item but its emtpy) 
list_selector_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</selector>
```

follow by an job_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/job_icon_circle"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/job_list_bubble"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">


            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:maxWidth="120dp"
                        android:text="Distance"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TableLayout>

                        <TableRow>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/postCode"
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:maxWidth="120dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:text="CW11 2XQ"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow>

                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/jobId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                        android:text="OrderId"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgNotes"
                        android:layout_width="75px"
                        android:layout_height="75px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/notes"
                        android:contentDescription="" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/OrderItemSummary"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_span="2"
                        android:width="275dp"
                        android:ellipsize="none"
                        android:maxLines="100"
                        android:maxWidth="275dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally a drawable job_list_bubble.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:top="30dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#F1EFF3" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:left="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#F1EFF3" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

You'll have to ignore some of the hackyness of this, the app is a neglected area picked up and created by non android people!

But the end result looks a little like this

[image]